# finding summary statistics of lowest number in column by group

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I want to find the mean, mode, 1st, 3rd percentiles, and standard deviation of the lowest (highest, and mean value) non-zero number of `year_hh_inc` when grouped by `regional_schlüssel`. Here is my data:

```
library(Rcurl)
x <- getURL('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dothemathonthatone/maps/master/maindf_2_Anon.csv')

maindf <- read.csv(text = x, row.names=NULL, head =TRUE, dec = ',')
```

I apply the following code:

```
  maindf %>%
  group_by(regional_schlüssel) %>%
  summarise(year_hh_inc = mean(min(year_hh_inc)))
```

This does not quite do what I want. It captures all of the minimum (maximum and standard deviation) values by `regional_schlüssel` but it does not tell me anything about their distribution.

Comment: By saying "the lowest non-zero number of `year_hh_inc`", what do you mean? For instance, When regional_schlüssel is 5112000, minimum value in year_hh_inc is 15000, if I am not mistaken. What do you wanna do with this number? Can you elaborate your situation?

Comment: @jazzurro thank you for asking. I would like to find the average (and standard deviation) of all the "lowest numbers"

Comment: So you want to identify the lowest number for each level in `year_hh_inc` and look for average of the numbers. Is that right?

Comment: @jazzuro yes sir.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Let me play with your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After exchanging messages, it seems that the following is one way for you to get the values that you want. First, I defined groups using `regional_schlüssel`. Then, I looked for the smallest value in each group. `values` contain the numeric values that you want to handle calculation. In the second `summarize()` I used a couple of functions to get the values that you are after.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

group_by(maindf, regional_schlüssel) %>% 
summarize(values = min(year_hh_inc)) %>% 
summarize(average = mean(values),
          sd = sd(values),
          mode = names(which.max(table(values))),
          quantile25 = quantile(values)[2],
          quantile75 = quantile(values)[4])

  average    sd mode  quantile25 quantile75
    <dbl> <dbl> <chr>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1  15035. 4292. 12271      12271      17500
```

Another way is the following. I think using `sumamry()` makes our lives easier.

```
group_by(maindf, regional_schlüssel) %>% 
summarize(values = min(year_hh_inc)) -> res

c(summary(res$values), sd = sd(res$values),
  mode = names(which.max(table(res$values)))) %>% 
enframe

  name    value           
  <chr>   <chr>           
1 Min.    -8              
2 1st Qu. 12271           
3 Median  14999.5         
4 Mean    15035.3142857143
5 3rd Qu. 17500           
6 Max.    29999           
7 sd      4291.76642645115
8 mode    12271
```

Comment: @jazzuro thank you for your solution; as a side question, do you think there is any way to put the distribution into a boxplot?

Comment: Something like this will do, I think. `group_by(maindf, regional_schlüssel) %>% summarize(values = min(year_hh_inc)) %>% mutate(id = "year_hh_inc") %>% ggplot(aes(x = id, y = values)) + geom_boxplot() + geom_jitter() + labs(x = "")`